# find() with regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, find

I am trying to parse a text file using C++ and check whether there a specific `PATTERN` exists or not.

The `PATTERN` consists of `;<n_WhiteSpaces><MACRO>`. 
In my code, these MACROs are already defined in a C++ Vector and we are using an iterator to check the existence of any one of these in a line.

```
vector<string> macroList;
vector<string>::const_iterator iter;

macroList.push_back("MACRO1");
macroList.push_back("MACRO2");
macroList.push_back("MACRO3");

string Line;
getline( *FilePtr, Line );

for( iter = macroList.begin(); iter != macroList.end(); iter++ )
{
  currentpos = Line.find( ;<n_WhiteSpaces>*iter );
}
```

Now, I'm quite sure that `find( ;<n_WhiteSpaces>*iter )` is syntactically wrong. Just as a reference of what I need to do actually, I'm providing this. 
My code should return the position of `;` followed by `n` White spaces(it could be 0 also) and then any MACRO from `macroList` vector.

Is it anyhow possible to avoid concatenation of two strings `;<n_WhiteSpaces>` & `*iter`? Please help me with `regex` for this find.

Newbie to C++. Sorry if my question is sounding silly! :P

Comment: The pattern needs to be enclosed in double quotes. And std::string::find() doesn't support regexes.

Comment: Use [std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)

Answer (score 1):

As @Galik pointed out, you need to use `regex_search` function, here is a simple code that can help you understand how to use it.

```
for( iter = macroList.begin(); iter != macroList.end(); iter++ )
{
    std::regex reg(";[\\s0]+" + *iter);
    std::smatch m;

    if (std::regex_search (yourLine, m, reg)) {
        currentPos = m.position();

        break;
    }
}
```

> Is it anyhow possible to avoid concatenation of two strings `;<n_WhiteSpaces>` & `*iter`?

Why would this be a problem? Anyway, I don't think it's possible.